# jQuery, Ajax, Multiple divs

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need help to display content in a popup div using ajax when the element is clicked

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.myDiv').click(function() {


      //Load a php file content from DB next to the clicked div


      });
    });

</script>

<div id="1" class="myDiv">Click me 1</div>
<div id="2" class="myDiv">Click me 2</div>
<div id="3" class="myDiv">Click me 3</div>
<div id="4" class="myDiv">Click me 4</div>
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.myDiv').click(function() {
    // Uncomment the lines below to make the AJAX function work. For demo, I have just
    // inserted a <span>.
    // $.get("/url", function (res) {
      $(this).append('<span>' + "This is AJAX Response." + '</span>');
    // });
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI';}
.myDiv {cursor: pointer; position: relative;}
.myDiv span {position: absolute; margin-top: -15px; top: 50%; height: 20px; border: 1px solid #999; padding: 5px 10px; margin-left: 15px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<div id="1" class="myDiv">Click me 1</div>
<div id="2" class="myDiv">Click me 2</div>
<div id="3" class="myDiv">Click me 3</div>
<div id="4" class="myDiv">Click me 4</div>
```

**Update**

If you wanna remove the previous `<span>`s after an AJAX call, you can do so with the following script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.myDiv').click(function() {
    // Uncomment the lines below to make the AJAX function work. For demo, I have just
    // inserted a <span>.
    // $.get("/url", function (res) {
      $(".myDiv span").remove();
      $(this).append('<span onclick="$(this).remove(); event.stopPropagation(); return false;">' + "This is AJAX Response." + '</span>');
    // });
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI';}
.myDiv {cursor: pointer; position: relative;}
.myDiv span {position: absolute; margin-top: -15px; top: 50%; height: 20px; border: 1px solid #999; padding: 5px 10px; margin-left: 15px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<div id="1" class="myDiv">Click me 1</div>
<div id="2" class="myDiv">Click me 2</div>
<div id="3" class="myDiv">Click me 3</div>
<div id="4" class="myDiv">Click me 4</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what i am lookin for thank you soooo much. Just when you click a span other span will disapear.